# Yii2 - get with multiple tables

Tags: yii, yii2

I have 5 tables I need to join in order to get all users for the team. Tables are:

```
User: iduser | firstName | lastName
Team: idteam | name
TeamUser: idteamuser | idteam | iduser
Portal: idportal | name
PortalTeam: idportalteam | idteam
```

In the **Portal** model I need to get all users for that portal. Is this possible?

Comment: It Possible!! Please Read Yii Relation: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation-in-yii-2-0

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a missing field (idportalteam) in Portal Model to link to other Models. When this is added you can create a relation for all models.

Portal:

```
public function getPortalTeam()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PortalTeam::className(), ['idportalteam' => 'idportalteam']);
}
```

PortalTeam:

```
public function getTeamUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TeamUser::className(), ['idteam' => 'idteam']);
}
```

TeamUser:

```
public function getTeam()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Team::className(), ['idteam' => 'idteam']);
}
```

TeamUser:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['iduser' => 'iduser']);
}
```

To get the models from Portal use:

```
$portal = (new Portal())->findOne(xyz);
$team = (($portal->portalTeam)->teamUser)->team;
$user = (($portal->portalTeam)->teamUser)->user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the -best- answer but can use ActiveQuery object and the join() method.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#join()-detail

Exp:

```
$data = \Portal::find()
    ->join($type, $table, $on = '', $params = [])
->andWhere([/* ... */])
->all();
```